# How to make a NodeJS request and pipe it into another response

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

So, i'm doing an api, to query a certain map service which require an API key. I want to keep the API key private so in my own api on the server, I will call a `http.request` to the map service, then immediately pipe it into the response to my own api user.

Here is sample code to illustrate the idea:

```js
import http from "http";

export default function handler(req, res) {
    http.request(`http://map.service.example.com/foo-bar`, (mapRes) => mapRes.pipe(res));
}
```

But so far, the code above doesn't work.

Any other possible way (with fetch maybe?) is welcome.

Comment: How it doesn't work? I guess you'll have to provide some more context.

Comment: [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback) contains a good example how to send an HTTP request. You need a `data` listener and an `end` listener. I think you have to `end` the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an `http.request` to go through you have to call its `end` method:

```
import http from "http";

export default function handler(req, res) {
    const mapReq = http.request(`http://map.service.example.com/foo-bar`, (mapRes) => mapRes.pipe(res));
    mapReq.end();
}
```

**OR**

You can use the `get` method:

```
import http from "http";

export default function handler(req, res) {
    http.get(`http://map.service.example.com/foo-bar`, (mapRes) => mapRes.pipe(res));
}
```